# How to get the new coordinates of a polygon after editing it?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I just want to know how to get the new coordinates of a polygon after editing it?

I did set the `Editable` proprety to my polygon to true, and I started changing the bounds of the polygon in the map, and when I finished editing, I want to get the new coordinates to my polygon , so I can store them in a MYSQL Database.

This is the code of my Polygon,

PS: the coordinates of my polygon are retrieved from a MYSQL Database.

```
cordonnees = [<?php echo $Cordinaates; ?>];
        poly_edit = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: cordonnees,
        strokeColor: "#0FF000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        editable:true,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#0FF000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    poly_edit.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo,

I Found it , this is The 2 listeners I Used :

The First Listener :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(patths, 'set_at', function() {
        new_paths = poly_edit.getPath();
                ...
});
```

The Second Listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(patths, 'insert_at', function() {
        new_lentgh = patths.getLength();
        new_paths = poly_edit.getPath();
            ...
});
```

it Works Like a Charm ^^

Comment: this is the link that Helped me : 
https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/bf3f0785def955a5

Answer (score 1):

The api reference is your friend: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon

```
var currentPaths = poly_edit.getPaths();
```

Comment: the problem is I change the shape of my Polygon in the Map , But the Changes do not apear, and I get only the Old Coordinates :(

Comment: Also in the docs: [How to get the new coordinates of a polygon after editing it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events).